# Android studio -How to allow user to send a file to a specific group using firebase storage

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-storage

Hello I am new to programming and i want to create an android application which has the following functionality:
A specific user should have the capability to upload file (like:text,image,pdf,word) to firebase storage and while uploading the file if he selects a radiobutton namely cse then the uploaded file should be sent only to the people who are registered by selecting the cse radiobutton from a radio group containing other branches like ece civil etc
Please help me !! Please

Thanks in advance 
Regards Rohit

Comment: What have you done? Do you think someone is gonna write all of that for you?

Comment: Nope i just want to know the logic behind it.Not the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Firebase Storage working. FB Storage doesn't handle logic, just storage.

Firebase Real Time Database will handle the logic. First upload the file to storage, get the url, upload and object containing the url to the database.

However you structure your database will allow users to see the file.